# Node.js and socket.io not run iis

Tags: node.js, iis-7, socket.io

You can not run simple application socket and node ... I have:

Windows 7 with IIS 7

Error:
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3001/socket.io/1/?t=1381529854815"

Please your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only IIS 8 has Web socket support and only windows 8 can run IIS 8 :-\

However, since you're using node then you should use the [socket.io module](http://socket.io) to do your web socket support. It tries to use web sockets but falls back on server-sent events and long polling if necessary. That means it will work with IIS 7 during development but will use web sockets when you publish it if the host supports them.

Comment: So is not possible to do it?  no even configuring the `io.configure(function(){
  io.set('transports',['xhr-polling']); //Use long-polling instead of websockets!
  io.set('resource','/myApp/server.js'); //Where we'll listen for connections.
});`

Comment: You can't use websockets on IIS 7 or lower. It's impossible without some sort of IIS extension that I'm not aware of.

Comment: I know you can only use websockets on iis8 but this guys claim to have a work around, I try for two days but it just does not work form here is the link what do you think.http://schmod.ruhoh.com/windows/socket-io-and-iis/

Comment: See my comment on your answer :). His workaround is the same as what I say in my answer. Socket.io works with IIS7 and lower by falling back onto AJAX long-polling (aka xhr-polling). It's not actually using websockets, just trying to simulate them the best it can.

Comment: Thank you,  if you said it works, I will try again until I get it working I want to use it on future apps but our servers are all iis 7.5. if you have another source where I can understand it better  I will appreciated thanks.

Comment: Just to make sure, you're using node.js for your server right? You're not trying to use socket.io in a .NET project are you?

Answer (score 0):

I try to use this work around but it did not work for me successfully, I have a iis7 on windows 7 here is the [link](http://schmod.ruhoh.com/windows/socket-io-and-iis/) that claims to have the solution.

http://schmod.ruhoh.com/windows/socket-io-and-iis/

Comment: His workaround is exactly the same as what I describe in my answer. Socket.io is built to fall back onto xhr-polling and server-sent events in the event that the server does not support the websocket protocol. By calling `io.set('transports', ['xhr-polling'])` all you're doing is telling socket.io to not even try websockets first and just go straight to xhr-polling. If you know your server doesn't support websockets then this is totally fine. Just keep in mind that if you deploy to a host that ***does*** support websockets, this option will make socket.io not even try to use websockets.